# Hand over PSD files for web slideshow

Tags: adobe-photoshop, website-design, client-relations

I agreed to make 5 images for a web slideshow for a client.

I haven't sent the quote for the work yet but they are already asking for the source file (psd file) I guess to create their own images in the future.

Should I charge for the psd file/the usage rights?

I know it's common to charge for that for print work but I am a bit confused here. My gut feeling is yes? TIA.

Comment: Yes, but if this wasn't agreed upon up front, then maybe you just let them have it this time. In the future, you'd ideally specify that in the contract.

Comment: Related and important: graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/21324/how-do-you-explain-the-value-of-native-files-to-an-uneducated-client/21327

Answer (score 2):

If you agreed to provide 5 files for a Web slide show and you have provided that to your client, that part of the agreement is fulfilled. If they are asking for the original PSD files, they intend to own the work. In that case it is entirely appropriate to charge for the PSD files and a good deal more than you agreed to charge them for the files for a Web slide show. There is also the copyright ownership issue here. If they want to modify the files then you need to either relinquish the copyright to them or give them rights to edit, modify, change, create derivatives, etc.

Perhaps you may start by inquiring what they need the PSD files for. I assume you may have multiple layers, filters, etc in that file, do they want all the layers intact or do they simply want larger pixel dimension, uncompressed files? Then decide how much it is worth to you to give up your work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response ACEkin. I will inquire about what they would like to do exactly with the psd file and quote accordingly.

Comment: +1 ACEkin is right @Sharlott! Don't give them the editable files. Suggestion: For the price of these editable files, think that giving them the files means no projects for you related to that kind of projects, therefore you make them save money. A base price for editable files can be minimum 3x the price of the project to compensate for at least the 3 next projects you won't do. For bigger files such as books or magazines, it can be more. Plus it also takes time to prepare so it's not only about the files. In worse case, it will give you the opportunity to negotiate for more projects!

Comment: @Sharlott If this answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted by clicking the little diamond icon next to this answer. It's also a good way to thank the person who took the time to help you!